# Autocommit off, BEGIN and warning about transaction in progress

Tags: postgresql, psql, autocommit

I like to have this in my `~/.psqlrc`:

```
\set autocommit off
```

I also like this at the top of my `filename.sql` scripts:

```
BEGIN;
```

...in case those scripts are run by others who uses autocommit.

However, this emits warnings:

```
WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
```

How can I turn off those annoying warnings? Is there some sort of `BEGIN IF NOT ALREADY BEGUN` command?

Comment: But that just emits another warning: `WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress`. The point is getting rid of those warnings, not replace one annoying warning with another.

Comment: Come to think of it......... I can just replace `BEGIN;` with `\set autocommit off` in my .sql scripts.  ...I think I'll just delete this question.........

Comment: You already got a perfect answer by Laurenz.

Answer (score 6):

Your two settings contradict each other.

If you enable autocommit mode in `psql`, your scripts should look like this:

```
-- statement 1
-- statement 2
...
COMMIT;
-- statement 3
...
COMMIT;
```

That is because autocommit mode will automatically add a `BEGIN` before the first statement and before eache statement after a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.
That is because PostgreSQL does not have an autocommit mode, so `psql` is “faking it”.

Now if your script starts with a `BEGIN`, that will result in two `BEGIN`s right after each other, which will result in the observed warning.

Maybe it would be best to start your scripts with

```
\set autocommit on
```

to make sure everything is consistent.

Comment: I understand why I get the warning, I was just wondering if there is a way to suppress it. (I also think `\set autocommit off` should be the default, but thats another topic).

Comment: I extended my answer for that.